# Serving an S3 static website via CloudFront and making the bucket private?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have seen guides for allowing aws users to make a bucket private but serve some of its objects through cloudfront. I have been trying to do the same with an entire static site hosted in an s3 bucket, and nothing seems to be working. But I can't find anything explicitly telling me it's not possible.

Is it possible to use the S3 static website hosting feature in a private bucket? Could users only access the site via the cloudfront distribution, but not by going to the s3 bucket URL's proper?

Comment: Here is the official documentation you are looking for: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html

Comment: The guide doesn't apply to this question though: `If you use an Amazon S3 bucket configured as a website endpoint, you must set it up with CloudFront as a custom origin. You can’t use the origin access identity feature described in this topic. `. So you have to set up a custom origin, and try to combine it with the signing process.

Comment: But the real question is why you want to set it up with website hosting in the first place? Can you elaborate on that @hipsterstomper69

Comment: Just to see if it's possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, OAI does not work when you use the S3 static website feature.

The best way to do what you want is to [add a custom header in cloudfront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/add-origin-custom-headers.html).
Generate a complex and long string like it was a password and pass it in the referer header.

Then add a bucket policy that lets everybody (principal: "*") to perform a getobject but [at the condition that a specific header is specified](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4).

Example of a bucket policy:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow get requests originating from your Cloudfront distribution.",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectVersion"],
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{"aws:Referer": "9vzeMAVjTKCWXjbBNFsCnNRsPKqMYk6achgLXu5S"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Don't forget to disable the S3 public access block feature on your bucket.

You can find a more complete guide there: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/?nc1=h_ls